# Matriz 3x3 em PHP, como mostrar apenas os elementos das pontas

Tags: php, matriz

gostaria de saber se existe alguma condição específica para que eu imprima apenas os elementos da ponta da matriz(1,5,13,17).

```
 <?php
        $matriz = [
                [1,3,5],//1
                [7,9,11],//0,2
                [13,15,17]//1
            ];

            for($l=0; $l<3; $l++){
                for($c=0; $c<3; $c++){
                if(condição)
        echo $matriz[$l][$c];
                }

            }

        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para recuperar as extremidades não tem necessidade de fazer um for, basta ir direto nas posições que você quer.

```
// Primeira coluna da primeira linha
$matriz[0][0];

// Última coluna da primeira linha
$matriz[0][count($matriz[0]) - 1];

// Primeira coluna da última linha
$matriz[count($matriz) - 1][0];

// Última coluna da última linha
$matriz[count($matriz) - 1][count($matriz[count($matriz) - 1]) - 1];

// Última coluna da última linha (nesse caso, considerando que as linhas sempre serão do mesmo tamanho)
$matriz[count($matriz) - 1][count($matriz[0]) - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar as funções `reset()` e `end()`, desta maneira uma nova matriz será criada com o primeiro e último elemento da matriz principal. Utilizando o `foreach()` você irá ler todo o conteúdo da nova matriz criada e utilizar as mesmas funções para capturar o primeiro e último elemento de cada array da matriz.

```php
  <?php
    $matriz = [
                [1,3,5],//1
                [7,9,11],//0,2
                [13,15,17]//1
              ];

        $matrizPrimeiroUltimo[] = reset($matriz);
        $matrizPrimeiroUltimo[] = end($matriz);

    foreach ($matrizPrimeiroUltimo as $valor) {
        $primeiroUltimo[] = reset($valor);
        $primeiroUltimo[] = end($valor);
    }

    var_dump($primeiroUltimo);
```

[Documentação PHP reset()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.reset.php)

> **reset()** retrocede o ponteiro interno de array para o primeiro elemento e retorna o valor do primeiro elemento do array, ou FALSE se o array for vazio.

[Documentação PHP end()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.end.php)

> **end()** avança o ponteiro interno de array até o seu último elemento, e retorna-o.

[Documentação PHP foreach()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php)